# The WebStorm do not recognise .vue file

Tags: webstorm

I created a Vue project by Vue-CLI, when I use WebStorm open the project, but the `.vue` file seems like plain text, there is no highlight syntax.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

The code are bellow:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img src="./assets/logo.png">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <h2>Essential Links</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="https://vuejs.org" target="_blank">Core Docs</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://forum.vuejs.org" target="_blank">Forum</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://chat.vuejs.org" target="_blank">Community Chat</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://twitter.com/vuejs" target="_blank">Twitter</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h2>Ecosystem</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://router.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-router</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vuex.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vuex</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/" target="_blank">vue-loader</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue" target="_blank">awesome-vue</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

h1, h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

a {
  color: #42b983;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that [Vue.js](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9442-vue-js) plugin is enabled in **Preferences | Plugins** - it is bundled with recent WebStorm versions. If it's installed and enabled, make sure that `*.vue` extension is assigned to **Vue.js Templates** in **Preferences | Editor | File Types**, and that your don't have `App.vue` pattern registered for **Text** file type there

Answer (score 6):

First, add the [Vue.js](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9442-vue-js) plugin in `Preferences | Plugins`.

Then you should

Go to : WebStorm -> Preferences -> Editor -> File Types -> HTML:

[image]

in the `Registered Patterns` there is no `*.vue`.

Add the `*.vue` in the `Registered Patterns` like this:

[image]

Then apply it.